# Check if multi-line string matches expression

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have this:

```
declare_result=$(declare -f cd);
```

which yields this verbatim:

```
cd () 
{ 
    prev_cd "$@";
    echo "botch cd hook invoked.";
    run_botch
}
```

how  can I check if $declare_result matches "run_botch"?

is it as simple as:

```
if [[ "$declare_result" == *"run_botch"* ]];
```

if will that not work for multi-line strings? That is my primary concern is that it won't work for newline separated strings.

Comment: Works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your example works just fine. `bash` has no issue with matching against a string that contains embedded newlines.

With a pattern like `*$'run_botch\n'*` it can even match the newline after the string `run_botch`.